# How to measure total STL container memory consumption?

Tags: c++, stl

As in the title: given an object of type of some STL container (e.g. `std::vector<int>` or `std::set<MyClass>`) I would like to know their memory consumption --- that is --- how much memory is consumed to store the elements, the auxiliary data for each element and the container size. I assume that the objects stored do not allocate any additional memory.

For a `std::vector<int> v` I can add:

```
sizeof(std::vector<int>) + v.capacity()*sizeof(int)
```

because vectors do not store any auxiliary data per element. But how can I do it for other containers?

I can live with non-constant time complexity.

Comment: Probably best to provide your own logging allocator. That wouldn't work for existing code, but it'd let you track exactly when and how containers allocate memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own [STL allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_%28C++%29) and track the size of the memory requests placed to it, then just add the size of the container itself. [This article](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/allocators-stl/) gives a good overview of creating one.

Comment: The second link seems to be broken

Comment: @CygnusX1 I've fixed the link to the rehomed version of the article. However is exceedingly old, you are better off using something more up to date as a reference, eg. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator